# JAX-WS Generate parameter type for xs:hexBinary

Tags: java, jax-ws

I made a webservice endpoint, Java first, providing a method returning javax.activation.DataHandler for binary data of content, which mime type is  "application/octet-stream". I enabled MTOM support, which isn't enabled by default.

According to this table [JAX-WS supported types](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html) , DataHandler is associated to xs:base64Binary XML type, and generated WSDL shows it. I would like to make JAX-WS generate a xs:hexBinary type instead. Does someone know how to? I couldn't find it in manual ( [IBM docs on enabling MTOM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_enablemtom.html) ), nor any annotation used to achieve this goal..

I use JDK8, deploying on JBOSS EAP6.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried through annotation @XmlSchemaType(name="hexBinary") but I does not affect the generated xml type used in WSDL

Comment: Another test with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class) : leaded to "IllegalAnnotationsException HexBinaryAdapter is not applicable to the field type javax.activation.DataHandler"
Which seams to mean that DataHandler can only be parsed to base64Binary ? No clue on that in documentation..

Comment: I also tested with a package-info.java containing @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "hexBinary", type = javax.activation.DataHandler.class)
But it remains of type base64Binary in generated wsdl. I'm running out of potential solutions..

Answer (score 0):

I had found solution to this problem, you have to create wrapped transport object.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.HexBinaryAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "fileWrapper", propOrder = {
        "binaryFile",
        "base64File"
})
public class FileWrapper {
    @XmlElement(type = String.class, required = false)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "hexBinary")
    private byte[] binaryFile;
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private byte[] base64File;

    public byte[] getBinaryFile() {
        return binaryFile;
    }

    public void setBinaryFile(byte[] binaryFile) {
        this.binaryFile = binaryFile;
    }

    public byte[] getBase64File() {
        return base64File;
    }

    public void setBase64File(byte[] base64File) {
        this.base64File = base64File;
    }
}
```

And your web service API:

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;

@Endpoint
@WebService(name = "ExampleApi", targetNamespace = "http://example-api.com/")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class ExampleApi {
    @WebMethod
    public Boolean uploadFile(@WebParam(name = "fileWrapper")
                              @XmlElement(required = true)
                                      FileWrapper fileWrapper) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It will generate WSDL with content (snippet, not whole WSDL)

```
  <xs:complexType name="uploadFile">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fileWrapper" type="tns:fileWrapper"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="fileWrapper">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="binaryFile" type="xs:hexBinary"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="base64File" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```